# Mildly distressing missing pixel on left side of tabs

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

Once you see it you'll see it everywhere.

[image]

Comment: Looks fine on my computer.. http://i.stack.imgur.com/AFnHQ.png .. what's your browser/OS?

Comment: Looks a [little different on mine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/U6yDq.png). Chromium 30 on Ubuntu 12.04. [Maybe your enhancement algorithms aren't good enough?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vxq9yj2pVWk) :D

Comment: I'm using Firefox (ESR 17) on Windows (2003).

Comment: norepro here as well, Chrome 31.0.1650.63 Win7

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need

Comment: Firefox 17? Windows 10-years-old? How far back do you expect a web site in 2013 to cater to, especially for something so trivial?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Apologies but it never occurred to me I might be the only person seeing it.

Comment: I don't doubt that you're not the only person seeing it. I just don't think it's reasonable to expect that they're going to drop everything to fix minor visual inconsistencies in browsers so old that there's no chance any modern workarounds will improve the situation anyway.

Comment: Reproduced on latest Firefox (25.0.1) on Windows 8.1

Comment: IE 10 on Win RT has the missing pixel on the *other corner*. Weird.

Answer (score 5):

That's just the way borders render, in Firefox, on the **one px** scale.

In the image below the top box has a border of 20px and the bottom box has a border of 1px.

[image]

[image]

So, if you make the bottom border transparent... It will account for your missing pixel.

[Example in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nASp4/)

Answer (score 2):

I see something a little similar on both sides of the tab, in Chrome  31.0.1650.57 on Mac OS X 10.9:

> [image]

(In my case, it looks like a reasonable attempt to round a 1-px corner.)

However, this is most likely going to come down to how each browser renders certain CSS elements. It isn't a bug SO is going to be able to fix without getting all of the browsers to work exactly the same (good luck with that - especially given the triviality of the issue, and the fact that [the browser you're using isn't even officially supported at all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)).

Answer (score 2):

Greasemonkey fix:

```
GM_addStyle('#tabs a:hover { border-bottom-width:0; height:25px; }');
GM_addStyle('#tabs a.youarehere { border-bottom-width:0; height:31px; }');
```

That removes the tab's bottom border (instead of coloring it white), then increases the height of the tab by 1 pixel to cover the #ccc baseline using the tab background instead of the tab border.